# Crystallite size in thin films

Tags: crystals, x-ray-crystallography

First thing is, what is the difference between grain size and crystallite size? Well, I have basic knowledge between the two. As far as I know the grain size is single crystal within the bulk/thin film form while crystallite size is single crystal in a powder form. Now my dilemma is about differentiating the two in terms of what "terms" to be used (grain size or crystallite size?). Using SEM I'm sure that what I'm measured is "GRAIN SIZE". But when it comes to XRD, I don't know if its right to used "crystallite size" term? since my sample is in a bulk/thin film form, and the values that I measured in SEM is larger compared to XRD. (So obviously grain size is much larger to crystallite size). So please help me thanks!

Comment: Are your SEM grains actually single crystal? Or are there twin boundaries? Do you know that your film is equi-axis, or are they thinner in one direction (i.e. the thin film through-thickness)?

Comment: My SEM images have twin boundaries. I don't what is equi-axis is?. Yes some part is thinner and some part is thicker.